# Uninstalling easy_install, pip, pip3, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I'm struggling to see how all of these components are connected, - what installs what and so on. My installation is a mess. Several installations of Python (and I don't know which one is the native one - and which one can be removed). When I create a new virtualenv (`mkvirtualenv venv`) and activate it. If I then write `pip3 install django`, then it gives me the error: `Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).` Which tells me, that the virtualenvs are pointing to Python2.7 (instead of Python3), and pip (instead of pip3).

I've just had it with all this crap. How do I remove all that I can possibly remove, so I can start fresh? I want to install all version of:

- pip
- pip3
- easy_install
- python (all other installations than the native ones)
- virtualenv
- virtualenvwrapper

I have Homebrew installed - and my plan is to install most/all of it again afterwards properly using Homebrew. And how can I see, if the current program is installed using Homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see, if you have installed python with brew do:

```
brew info python
```

and

```
brew info python3
```

To see which python installation is used do:

```
which python
```

and

```
which python3
```

Original macos python binaries are in `/usr/bin/`, homebrew python binaries are in `/usr/local/bin/`. You can also use the `which` command on `pip`, `pip3`, `easy_install`, `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Can easy_install be deleted from the operating system - or is it part of the native package?

Comment: `easy_install` comes with the standard macos installation and with the homebrew installation. I recommend not to delete any binary in `/usr/bin`.